# Remove comma from an array element when element is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**This is my HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" value="" onkeyup="dateOfBirth('stepbirth')">
<input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" value="" onkeyup="dateOfBirth('stepbirth')">
```

Here is my javascript to collect the value for each element.

```
var DoB = []; 
  $(".date_of_birth").each(function(){
      DoB.push($(this).val());
  });

  var newDob = DoB.slice(0,-1);

  var stepVar = newDob;
```

It is working fine. When there are more values it sends values like this

`20/02/2002,03/03/2003`

which is fine.But the issue i have event on keyup on each input field. When the user fill in both fields and after if remove the data from one field then it sends values like this..

```
20/02/2002,
```

So my script stops validation here because of comma it expect the values like

```
20/02/2002,03/03/2003
```

or

```
20/02/2002
```

How can i remove comma here until input is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the commas, fix the problem at the source. The cause is due to the fact that you always push the value to the array even if the value is empty. To fix this, check the value before calling `push()`.

```
var DoB = []; 
$(".date_of_birth").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).val().trim();
  if (value.length)
    DoB.push($(this).val());
});
```

Alternatively you can make this more succinct by using `map()`. If you return `null`, then the element will not be added to the array.

```js
var DoB = $(".date_of_birth").map(function() {
  return $(this).val().trim() || null;
});
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this thread..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306556/remove-the-disabled-class-when-get-response-1-from-the-php-script-and-radio-butt/57306869?noredirect=1#comment101112842_57306869

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[toArray](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)" and filter all elements with values:

```
 var DoB = $(".date_of_birth").toArray().filter(function(el) {return $(el).val().trim();});
```

or using arrow function

```
var DoB = $(".date_of_birth").toArray().filter(el => $(el).val().trim());
```